# MongoDB update atomic operation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongo-java-driver

I'm just learning MongoDB and implementing a URL shortener as a POC. I was going through a tutorial on NodeJS/Mongoose and saw this method:

```
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, [update], [options], [callback])
```

Are both update AND callback operations atomic? Or is only the update operation atomic?

**If both are atomic, how to do this in Java**? The Mongo-java-driver has this method

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options);
```

But obviously there is no callback supported. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Callback is available in mongo java driver from [version 3.0](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-30-java-driver). If you are using a lesser version of mongo java driver, please upgrade it to version 3.0 or later.

Please see this [post](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.mongodb.client.model.FindOneAndUpdateOptions) for findOneAndUpdate callback sample

Other useful posts

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/tree/master/driver-async

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.mongodb.async.SingleResultCallback

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/?_ga=1.13498046.849992754.1476359743

Atomicity

All write operations in MongoDB are atomic on the level of a single document.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/update-documents/
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/write-operations-atomicity/

Comment: In the first link you posted, I'm looking at Example 3, which uses findOneAndUpdate(). But I don't see it using a callback? Also, are the update and callback operations together atomic?

Comment: Yes in example 3, they have assigned the value to a variable, please see example 1,2 and 4 in that they have used callback.